# Is there a website/tool which can generate a reachability map from a given point?

Tags: online-resources, planning, maps

I'm currently planning a four-day holiday with friends of mine who live in different regions of Germany. Now we're trying to find a holiday home that everyone of us can reach in less then 3.5h by car.

Now this is definitely doable by trial and error, but can become quite frustrating at times. I am wondering if I can create a reachability map, maybe by a web-based generator tool where I just enter the starting points and the maximum travel time and the tool generates a map with the areas in which I can look for that holiday home.

Now my question: does anyone know such a tool?

Here's a reachability map (created [manually](http://nkblog.nkdev.de/karte-entfernung-in-fahrstunden/)) for the city of Leipzig as the sole starting point, with the lines representing hours of driving time:
[image: Reachability Map]

Comment: The Geographic Information Systems network has some related questions -- a quick googling reveals at least http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2967/creating-drive-time-polygons-using-open-source-tools and http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31057/create-drive-time-polygon-around-a-map-point

Comment: Let us know if you find a solution. :)

Comment: My latest attempt was a combination of [How far can I travel](http://www.freemaptools.com/how-far-can-i-travel.htm) (HFCIT) and Google Earth. HFCIT accepts one starting point and a max travel time, so I used it four times and each time then exported a KML file that I fed into Google Earth to get a visual overlap. As a workaround, this works OK, although with 4 layers of different color, it gets pretty hard to identify the overlap area. The bigger problem though is the low quality of the data that HFCIT generates in the first place - if anyone knows a better tool for this, let me know :-)

Comment: https://developer.here.com/blog/interactive-isoline-grid-with-here-react-leaflet — just leaving this here for anyone interested.

Answer (score 3):

Does [GeoMidPoint](http://www.geomidpoint.com/) accomplish what you have in mind? It calculates the midpoint between different addresses. I punched in 5 cities around my area, and it indicated the location that was in the middle. This would not indicate, specifically, what is 3.5 hours from each of you, but it would give you the opportunity to all drive an equal distance.

Comment: This calculates the geographic midpoint but does not at all take driving constraints (routes, traffic speed) into account as far as I can see. So while it is at most a partial answer, it might be a starting point and certainly good to know.

Comment: Is this your website?

Comment: Nope, just one I have used in the past.

Answer (score 3):

You could try out this site. Originally for walking but works for car as well. https://www.walkscore.com/professional/travel-time-js-api.php#widget-examplev

Comment: Do you have any connection to this site? Could you explain how you're supposed to use it for the requested purpose as it wasn't obvious to me.

Comment: It does look very useful given the examples, but I think you'd have to overlay multiple maps to get what the OP needs. Anyway, +1 and bookmarked

Answer (score -4):

Isochrone maps for a bunch of European cities:

http://emptypipes.org/2015/05/20/europe-isochrone-map/

Comment: This doesn't answer the question : you can select only one city (within a very limited subset), and the times given are for train transportation (and walking...).

Comment: -1 IMHO this answer should be a comment, not an answer